# What words go in the id_just flag of ternaryplot from the vcd package

Tags: r

The `id_flag` help section only says `c("center", "center")`.  I'm trying to figure out how to get the label above the dots representing the data points.  As it is currently, they is below and overlap the outside labels rendering it unreadable.

```
feldspars <- data.frame(or=c(41, 94), Al=c(53, 4.6), An=c(4.3,0.7))
ternaryplot( feldspars, 
         scale = 100, 
          pch = 19, 
         cex = 0.4, 
        dimnames = c("Orthoclase", "Albite", "Anorthite"),
        labels = c("outside"),
        main = "Feldspars: Samples 24b and 41",
        id = c("MS-13-24b", "MS-14-41"),
        id_just = c("right", "center")
      )
```

Any ideas?  I've tried right, left, up, down, top, bottom, these words all failed.  I've googled for the manual, and I even tried finding the code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Now it's your turn to checkmark Henrik's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The basic position of the id:s (i.e. under the points) seems hard-coded. If you type `ternaryplot` in the R console you see the code:
`function (x, scale = 1, dimnames = NULL, dimnames_position = c("corner",`

`...lots of code...`

In the last `grid.text` section, you find that `id_just` is used as values for the `just` argument:

`if (!is.null(id)) 
    grid.text(x = xp, y = unit(yp + 0.015, "snpc") - 0.5 * 
                size, label = as.character(id), just = id_just, gp = gpar(col = id_color, 
                                                                          cex = cex))`

For a better description than in `?ternaryplot` of possible values of `id_just`, see `?grid.text`.

If you change the "`-`" in `y = unit(yp - 0.015, "snpc")` to a "`+`", save the edited function and set `id_just` to `c("left", "bottom")` the labels looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Points to Henrik who did the hard work:

```
 ?grid::grid.text
```

"The justification of the text relative to its (x, y) location. If there are two values, the first value specifies horizontal justification and the second value specifies vertical justification. Possible string values are: "left", "right", "centre", "center", "bottom", and "top". For numeric values, 0 means left alignment and 1 means right alignment."